# Video that shows a series of HTML based text overlaid

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

I have a client who is working on a showreel, within the showreal they wanted to display key headlines at certain points in the video. They could include the text in the video itself, however, I wanted to include in as HTML text so that they can edit via the CMS. The question is, from a frontend point of view I am trying to get my head around how I might do this. I can easily place a text field over the video, which by the way is a vimeo video which I am pulling in using the  tag. It's just a case of how to target key points in the video?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: if you can add event handler to the video then you can track the currentTime and use that to determine when to display the overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use subtitles?  You could build a simple page for editing them (start time, end time, text) and then upload that to Vimeo using your key (which I assume is feasible - most video hosting services will do this).

Comment: I would want to style the headline and add transitions using CSS, I am guessing this wouldn't be possible with subtitles?

Comment: You can use CSS in your VTT files.  See this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video

Comment: That's great, I never knew that, thanks for the tip Doug :)